# (sed) Delete an entire line if either condition is true

Tags: sed

I am working with a csv file that looks like this

```
KMGM more words and things
7HSQ other more words and stuff
JHGQ8 even more other stuff
KH21 and more stuff
```

The only valid lines are those where the first word is a letter followed by exactly three characters that could be letters or numbers.  In the above example, the lines containing `KMGM` and `KH21` are valid.  I want to delete the others using sed.

I just wanted to make a condition say,

```
IF first character is not a letter OR 
   fifth character is not a space OR 
   characters two, three, or four contain 
       anything other than an uppercase letter or a number
THEN
    delete the entire line
```

I just don't know how to formulate this in sed.  I had a similar problem yesterday but the rows were exactly four characters long.  Now we have added information and the rows vary in length.

Comment: Don't merge the cases if you don't have to. Just use multiple match statements.

Comment: That sounds good.  How can I match a particular character position (eg, the fifth character on the line)?

Comment: `s/^.... /` will match any line with a space in the fifth position, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you.

```
sed -n '/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]\{3\} /p'
```

Instead deleting, this only keeps lines which match all your conditions. Like this:

```
IF first character is a letter AND
   fifth character is a space AND
   characters two, three, or four contain 
       an uppercase letter or a number
THEN
    keep (print) the line
```

- `/p` does the printing if regex matches
- `-n` avoids printing otherwise

If you want to edit the file in-place, you can run it like this:

```
sed --in-place=.bak -n '/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]\{3\} /p' yourfile.csv
```

It will delete the lines you want to delete directly in the file and stores a backup of the original file in `yourfile.csv.bak`.

Comment: Does it matter that all the lines contain additional words and stuff afterward?

Comment: No, it only checks the beginning of line to decide whether to keep it or not.

Comment: If you want to keep default printing, you can invert the pattern and use `d`: `sed '/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]\{3\}/!d`. You can also use character classes for more general matches: `sed '/^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]\{3\}/!d` (alpha and alnum are case insensitive, so you may need to use `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:upper:][:digit:]]`)

Comment: @Qualia, you missed a space in your both expressions. Otherwise, great solutions!